# Can't find BadRequest method

Tags: asp.net-core

I read this announcement

https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/153

`HttpBadRequest` is now `BadRequest`

but I can't find a **BadRequest**  method and what happened to **this.Ok(Object)** method?

Comment: return new BadRequestResult();

Comment: You would be better off asking this on the forum for that topic: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4118

Comment: You should add the info if you are using POCO controllers or if your contollers derive from `Controller` base class. If you derive from the base class, it should be available. In Poco containers it's not available for obvious reasons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Regarding Bad Requests**

As mentioned in [this related GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4118#issuecomment-186405070), you would actually create a new instance of a [`BadRequestResult()`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a78f77afde003c4a3fcf5dd7b6dc13dd9c85f825/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/BadRequestResult.cs) object :

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
     return new BadRequestResult();
}
```

**Regarding `Ok()` Requests**

As far as the `Ok()`method goes, it actually comes from the controller itself, so it should still work as you might expect :

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
     return this.Ok(yourObject);
}
```

However, there is also an [`OkResult()`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a78f77afde003c4a3fcf5dd7b6dc13dd9c85f825/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/OkResult.cs) and [`OkObjectResult()`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a78f77afde003c4a3fcf5dd7b6dc13dd9c85f825/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/OkObjectResult.cs), which can return an OK request and one that accepts an object overload as well :

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
     return new OkResult();
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
     return new OkObjectResult(yourObject);
}
```